# Thumbnail plugin in wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, thumbnails

Is there any plugin in wordpress which will display the article image on home page in small thumbnail ?
i.e. i want to display the article image (which may be of any size) in thumbnail size image on home page.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the image by itself, or as some sort of hero?

Are you a developer, or do you need some sort of out-of-the-box solution?

Comment: I'm also interested in this. I'm using WordPress 3.4.2. A plug-in would be nice.